# Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class ingelby\toolbox\helpers\PublicIdBehavior does not exist' in yii2 advance

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am getting this error.

```
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class ingelby\toolbox\helpers\PublicIdBehavior does not exist' 

in D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:428

Stack trace:
#0 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(428): ReflectionClass->__construct('ingelby\\toolbox...')
#1 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(364): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('ingelby\\toolbox...')
#2 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('ingelby\\toolbox...', Array, Array)
#3 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('ingelby\\toolbox...', Array, Array)
#4 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(750): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#5 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(734): yii\base\Component->attachBehaviorInternal(2, Array)
#6 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(603): yii\base\Component->ensureBehaviors()
#7 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\BaseActiveRecord.php(925): yii\base\Component->trigger('init')
#8 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php(109): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->init()
#9 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#10 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(375): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#11 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('frontend\\models...', Array, Array)
#12 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(345): yii\di\Container->get('frontend\\models...', Array)
#13 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\StaticInstanceTrait.php(37): yii\BaseYii::createObject('frontend\\models...')
#14 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\ActiveQuery.php(447): yii\base\Model::instance()
#15 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\ActiveQuery.php(146): yii\db\ActiveQuery->buildJoinWith()
#16 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\QueryBuilder.php(227): yii\db\ActiveQuery->prepare(Object(yii\db\mysql\QueryBuilder))
#17 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\ActiveQuery.php(316): yii\db\QueryBuilder->build(Object(yii\db\ActiveQuery))
#18 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Query.php(237): yii\db\ActiveQuery->createCommand(Object(yii\db\Connection))
#19 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\ActiveQuery.php(133): yii\db\Query->all(NULL)
#20 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\frontend\models\Event.php(86): yii\db\ActiveQuery->all()
#21 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\frontend\controllers\SiteController.php(212): frontend\models\Event::getEvents(Array, 50976)
#22 [internal function]: frontend\controllers\SiteController->actionIndex()
#23 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#24 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#25 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#26 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('', Array)
#27 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#28 D:\xamppnew\htdocs\nfsp\frontend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#29 {main}
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This is package issue please update the package.https://github.com/ingelby/toolbox

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a package in a folder vendor.
Try to execute command "composer install".
if it doesn’t help, show please composer.